# ReadOnly field saved with NULL value

Tags: python, odoo, crm

On `CRM` opportunity form view, i added `readonly="1"` for probability field. When i saved, whatever the value of my probability, it's stored with NULL value.
Is it a bug on `OpenERP` ?

Comment: Do you have a default value defined for it?

Comment: No i didn't define any default value for probability field.

Comment: Then the value in that field is always empty, so that's why you're getting a `NULL` value

Comment: What's your field type which you added readonly="1" ??

Comment: When i remove readonly="1", it's stored with the value that i entred. Probability field type is float.

Answer (score 1):

We have two values like client side and server side. In Server side coding done like float value have 0.0 etc. Read only field doesn't take value from the Client side because it's read only. In View, we see that 0.0 for float value because of server side coding. If you remove read only attribute, you can get value from the Client side and that value pass to the Server and store into the Database. Field with read only attribute, can't get value from the client side and store NULL into the Database.

Hope this will help you.

Comment: @Odera you're wright, field with read only attribute can't get value from the client side. I solved my problem by making the field Readonly after creation of the record. 

    <field name="probability" class="oe_inline" widget="integer" attrs="{'readonly':   [('x_created','=',True)]}"/>

Answer (score 1):

In openerp Readonly field is use to just display the content but it will not store any data in database. So it is displaying Null value.
Readonly is just for informative purpose only.

Answer (score 0):

I think its a bug in openerp. I have created a patch for that. In the openerp addons, web module, goto static/src/js/view_form.js.

```
Index: view_form.js
===================================================================
--- openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js   
+++ openerp/addons/web/static/src/js/view_form.js   
@@ -833,11 +833,9 @@
                     // Special case 'id' field, do not save this field
                     // on 'create' : save all non readonly fields
                     // on 'edit' : save non readonly modified fields
-                    if (!f.get("readonly")) {
-                        values[f.name] = f.get_value();
-                    } else {
-                        readonly_values[f.name] = f.get_value();
-                    }
+                   values[f.name] = f.get_value();
+                    if (f.get("readonly"))
+                       readonly_values[f.name] = f.get_value();
                 }
             }
             if (form_invalid) {
```

Answer (score 0):

change your probability field to function field, and write a function (ex _get_probability). And keep the current probability calculating function as it is. Now default probability calculate function display the value and second function (_get_probability) will save the value.