# How to prevent user from inputting specific data on a field?

Tags: odoo

I want to prevent a user/group from editing a Purchase Order based on whether the partner reference field is blank or not. I tried to create a non global access control rule with the following domain rule:

```
[('partner_ref', '=', False)]
```

applied to create, write and delete. As expected, the user can't create, delete or change a purchase order with a non blank partner reference. But, if the user create a record with a blank partner reference, save it, and then edit, he can save it with a non blank field, which is not what I want. How can I prevent that?

Comment: we can make it `readonly field` when `partner_ref is False`.

Comment: You should be careful with readonly fields that are changed by  on change events. They are not saved to the database when you set them readonly

Comment: check this, i think this will help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880422/readonly-field-saved-with-null-value/20882835#20882835