# OpenERP - Read only field is not saved when "Save" button is pressed

Tags: odoo

In one view I have replaced field "default_code" with the field with the same name. When I set this field to be readonly, it is not saved when I click button "Save". It should be saved. Here is the code for the whole view:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<openerp>
    <data>
        <record id="product_config_form_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.config.form.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.template</field>
            <field name="type">form</field>
            <field name="inherit_id" ref="mrp.product_template_form_view_bom_button" />
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <label for="name" position="replace">
                    <label for="name" invisible="1"/>
                </label>
                <field name="name" position="replace">                      

                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <label for="class_id" string="Item Class" />
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <field name="class_id" colspan="3" nolabel="1" on_change="onchange_class_id(class_id)"
                        /> </div> 
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;">
                        <label for="name" string="Item Description"/>
                    </div>
                    <div style="font-size:10pt;" >
                        <field name="name" colspan="3" nolabel="1"/>
                    </div>

                </field>

                <field name="default_code" position="replace" >
                    <field name="default_code" string="Item Number" /> 
                </field>

                <xpath expr="//notebook/page[@string='Accounting']/group" position="replace">
                </xpath>
            </field>        
        </record>

        <record id="product_config_tree_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">product.config.tree.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.class</field>
            <field name="type">tree</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <tree string="Product">
                    <field name="default_code" string="Class ID" colspan="3" nolabel="1" />                         
                    <field name="name" string="Class Description" colspan="3" nolabel="1"/>                     
                </tree>
            </field>          
        </record>    

        <record id="class_search_view" model="ir.ui.view">
            <field name="name">class.search.view</field>
            <field name="model">product.class</field>
            <field name="arch" type="xml">
                <search string="Class">
                    <field name="name" string="Class Description" filter_domain="['|',('default_code','ilike',self),
                    ('name','ilike',self)]" />                                
                </search>
            </field>
        </record>

    </data>
</openerp>
```

Here is how I override the create() and write(), but it still does not work:

```
class product_product(osv.Model):
    _inherit = 'product.product'

    def create(self, cr, uid, vals, context=None):
        # raise osv.except_osv(_(u'TitleMessage'), _(u'Inside Create'))
        code = vals.get('default_code')
        vals.update({'default_code': code})
        print "\n\nCreate Value=> ",vals
        return super(product_product, self).create(cr, uid, vals, context)


    def write(self, cr, uid, ids, vals, context=None):
        # raise osv.except_osv(_(u'TitleMessage'), _(u'Inside Write'))
        print "\n\n\nCurrent Values =>", valswrite
        code = vals.get('default_code')
        print "\n\nWrite Value=> ",vals
        vals.update({'default_code': code}) 
        return super(product_product, self).write(cr, uid, ids, vals, context)
```

Comment: may be helpful to you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20880422/readonly-field-saved-with-null-value

Comment: Have read the post before, it doesn't solve my problem. Thanks.

Comment: No, I haven't because I am not sure where exactly to enter that piece of code.

Comment: Ok, I found the place to insert the patch and it worked. But, the patch code will be overwritten with new OpenERP version code. Am I right?

Comment: Is there any other way, like overiding write() or create() functions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Workaround. I have solved the issue by using a function field (invisible=False, readonly=True) which got updated with default_code (and mimics Item Number in the view) and I made original default_code readonly true and invisible true so it can be saved in the database.